# Can’t play Vine/Instagram videos in Chrome

Tags: video, google-chrome, browser

I installed Chrome because I have a new laptop. But now when I want to play Vine/Instagram videos, it doesn’t display them—I only get the sound. These videos are `.mp4` I guess.

What could be the problem? I’ve noticed that more people have this problem, but haven’t found a solution to this.

Comment: can you post a URL to one of those videos?

Comment: https://vine.co/v/haBb7KtMX9Z?fb_action_ids=433027163461946&fb_action_types=vine-app%3Apost&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%7B%22433027163461946%22%3A134553943418884%7D&action_type_map=%7B%22433027163461946%22%3A%22vine-app%3Apost%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D It works on my other computer in chrome. but it doesn't on my normal laptop.

Comment: This would seem to be a browser problem rather than a web app problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to use **Steve Wingfelder's** [workaround](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/297tWaAYyGo/uCgzS-pv1isJ) (numbers added for ease of reading)

> Temporary Fix:
>
> 1. Enter “Chrome://flags” in the address bar.
> 2. Find an entry that says
>      “Disable hardware-accelerated video decode.”
> 3. Click “Enable”.
> 4. Your
>      videos should now play just fine

Your problem also could be related to plugins. Some found **Gokul's** [suggestion](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/DrLRUK6g0wU/wdqPENzAqBUJ) to work:

> - Type **chrome://plugins** click on **+details** find the **PepperFlash** entry and click Disable.Use only Adobe plugin.
> - Check your extension causes the trouble.Disable them one by one and check.

Comment: This doesn't work for Chrome Version 50.0.2661.75 m.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary Fix:

Enter “Chrome://flags” in the address bar.
Find an entry that says “Disable hardware-accelerated video decode.”
Click “Enable”.
Your videos should now play just fine

It does work, however. your computer may run a LOT slower and become pretty hot while playing videos of high quality of even if you play a couple of them at the same time. I would limit viewing the videos of instagram and vine on your phone if I was you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be found here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/DrLRUK6g0wU

Refer to the workarounds posted by Gokul and Steve Wingfelder.

Comment: And when this link no longer works?

Comment: @AlEverett Fair point. It looks as though batpigandme later summarized the two solutions in his answer. Would best practice be to provide a permalink, or to include the relevant text in one's answer?

Comment: Best practice would be to post a useful summary _and_ a link to the source as credit and for more information. See also: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)

Answer (score 0):

Hardware acceleration is a feature in Adobe Flash Player that usually delivers a better video playing experience; however, sometimes it may cause issues.

The option to disable hardware acceleration is only available for certain versions of Adobe Flash Player system plug-in and operating systems (OS). [Follow these steps](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1230977) to see if the option is available:

- Right-click on the on the video you’re having issues with
- Click Settings
- If you see the option enable hardware acceleration, uncheck it. If you don’t see it, the option is not available for you.
- Click Close
- Refresh the page and check whether the video is working

Once you disable hardware acceleration, the setting will apply across all internet browsers on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was FireBug plugin that caused this issue, turning it off helped

Comment: Maybe It doesn't provide answer but it solves the issue and that what matters at the end. Why should I ask another question or add bounty? I solved the issue and now I wanted to help if someone had same problem, simple as that

Comment: Those were boilerplate comments from the review system. Your answer indeed offers a solution. I'm not sure how it could be expanded to give more details (maybe the FireBug version…). I'd say it's ok to keep it like this.

Answer (score -1):

My fix was enabling facebook owned content domain to connect in one Widgetblock 
addon

Comment: Can you explain how to do this, step by step?  Does the user need to have the WidgetBlock addon?   (What if they don’t?)